# If $f$ is a uniformly continuous function on a metric vector space, is there a continuous $g$ with $f=e^{{\rm i}g}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, logarithms, exponential-function, functional-equations

Let $E$ be a metric space and $$S^1:=\{z\in\mathbb C:|z|=1\}.$$ Say that $f\in C^0(E,S^1)$ is *inessential* if $$f=e^{{\rm i}g}\tag1$$ for some $g\in C^0(E,\mathbb R)$. We can show that

1. If $f\in C^0(E,S^1)$ with $f(E)\ne S^1$, then $f$ is inessential.
2. If $f_i\in C^0(E,S^1)$ with $$f_1(x)\ne-f_2(x)\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in E\tag2$$ and $f_1$ is inessential, then $f_2$ inessential.

In Appendix 2.5 of [Treatise on Analysis](https://www.elsevier.com/books/treatise-on-analysis/dieudonne/978-0-12-215507-9) the following corollary is shown:

[image]

If we take a look at the proof, we see that the compactness assumption is not needed as long as $f:E\times[0,1]\to S^1$ is uniformly continuous.

Now, the following is inferred from that corollary:

[image]

> It seems like the only reason why the closed ball in $\mathbb R^d$ is considered
> is that this is a compact metric vector space. Now I wonder, aren't we able to use precisely the same arguments to show that any uniformly continuous function $f:E\to S^1$ on a metric vector space is inessential?

### *EDIT*

It was remarked that this can be solved by some facts about algebraic topology. However, I'm not familiar with algebraic topology. So, I'd really appreciate if someone could provide an elementary answer (maybe imposing suitable assumptions, which are satisfied in the special case of $\mathbb R^d$).

Comment: I'd say that a continuous map $f\colon E\to S^1$ can only be essential if $E$ is not simply connected.

Comment: This is a consequence of the Lifting Lemma of Algebraic Topology. Its hypotheses require only that E be simply connected and locally path connected.

Comment: @Ruy Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with algebraic topology. Isn't there a more elementary answer (under suitable assumptions)?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Feel free to impose suitable assumptions. But please take note of my edit.

Comment: @0xbadf00d algebraic topological tools are necessary for these kinds of problems. If you consider the analogous complex logarithm problem for holomorphic functions (or in general monodromy on Riemann surfaces) you need to appeal to simply connectedness and local pathconnectedness and use a lifting lemma

Comment: @Reavered Please take a look at my answer below. I don't think that algebraic topology is really *necessary* as long as we provide suitable assumptions.

Comment: @Ruy I think I've found a solution which does not require algebraic topology. Please take a look at my answer below.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Please take note of the answer I've provided. Do you agree or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$
$\renewcommand{\S}{\mathbb{S}}$

The answer to the main question is **no** - continuous maps from a compact metric space into $\S^1$ can be essential. See the example:

> **Example.** Let $f \colon \S^1 \to \S^1$ be the identity: $f(z) = z$ for $x \in \S^1$. Then:
>
> - $f$ is continuous and $\S^1$ is a compact metric space, so $f$ is uniformly continuous,
> - there is no continuous map $g \colon \S^1 \to \R$ such that $f = e^{ig}$.

To see that the second statement is true, assume for the contrary that such a $g$ exists. Consider the continuous function $h \colon \R \to \R$ given by $h(t) = g(e^{it})$. Now for each $t \in \R$ we have
$$ e^{i h(t)} = e^{ig(e^{it})} = f(e^{it}) = e^{it}. $$
As in your Lemma 1, we see that $h(t)-t$ must be a multiple of $2\pi$. In other words, $t \mapsto h(t)-t$ is a continuous function from $\R$ to $2\pi \Z$, and as such has to be constant. Thus, $h(t) = t + 2k\pi$ for some fixed $k \in \Z$.

Coming back to our assumptions, we have $g(e^{it}) = t + 2k\pi$ for every $t \in \R$. But taking $t = 0$ and $t = 2\pi$ leads to a contradiction:
$$ 2k\pi = g(e^{0 \cdot i}) = g(1) = g(e^{2\pi \cdot i}) = (2k+1) \pi. $$

---

Let us dig a little deeper. You asked:

> It seems like the only reason why the closed ball in $\R^d$ is considered is that this is a compact metric vector space. Now I wonder, aren't we able to use precisely the same arguments to show that any uniformly continuous function $f \colon E \to \S^1$ on a metric vector space is inessential?

Now, you already know the answer is *no*. But you're right that this reasoning is quite general. You should be able to check yourself that it gives us:

> **Theorem.** Assume that the compact metric space $E$ admits a continuous function $r \colon E \times [0,1] \to E$ such that $r(\cdot,1)$ is the identity (i.e., $r(1,x) = x$), while $r(x,0)$ is constant (i.e., $r(0,x)=p$ for some fixed $p \in E$). Then every continuous map $f \colon E \to \S^1$ is inessential.

Such a map $r$ exists for the closed ball $E = \overline{B}^n$ (in fact, the proof of (Ap.2.6) relies on this) but not for the circle $E = \S^1$ (otherwise the example wouldn't work).

---

Finally, let me remark that there's no escaping from algebraic topology. This *is* algebraic topology, whether we like it or not. If you want to search for more, some vocabulary may be useful:

- A space $E$ is called *simply connected* if all continuous maps $f \colon E \to \S^1$ are inessential.
- The terms *essential* and *inessential* are usually replaced by *homotopically nontrivial* and *homotopically trivial*. These can be generalized to all possible target spaces.
- In (Ap.2.5), two maps $f(x,0)$ and $f(x,1)$ as are called *homotopic* and the map $f$ is called a *homotopy*.
- The map $g$ is called a *lifting* of $f$.
- For a general target space $X$ (in place of $\S^1$), one can consider a *cover* $\tilde{X} \to X$ (in place of $\R \to \S^1$, $t \mapsto e^{it}$) and talk about *liftings* in this more general context.
- Any space $E$ satisfying the assumptions of the theorem above is called *contractible*.

Of course, this is just vocabulary, in case you need it. Anyway, I strongly recommend [A. Hatcher's brilliant and entertaining book](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/ATpage.html).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't think that an algebraic topological argument is necessary to obtain the desired claim; at least under a suitable set of assumptions.

> **Lemma 1** Let $E$ be a metric space and $g_i\in C(E,\mathbb C)$ with $e^{g_1}=e^{g_2}$. Then $$\exists k\in\mathbb Z:g_1-g_2=2k\pi\tag1.$$

The proof easily follows from the continuity assumption and noting that $$e^{z_1}=e^{z_2}\Leftrightarrow\exists k\in\mathbb Z:2k\pi\tag2$$ for all $z_i\in\mathbb C$.

> **Theorem 2**: Let $\mathbb K=\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb K=\mathbb C$, $E$ be a normed $\mathbb K$-vector space, $\tau$ be a vector topology on $E$ such that the closed unit ball $\overline B_1(0)$ around $0$ is $\tau$-compact and $f:E\to\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ be $\tau$-continuous and uniformly norm-continuous. Then there is an unique norm-continuous $g:E\to\mathbb C$ with $g(0)=0$ and $e^g=f$.

Fix $r>0$ for the moment. Since $\overline B_r(0)$ is $\tau$-compact and $f$ is $\tau$-continuous, $f(\overline B_r(0))$ is compact and hence (since $0\not\in f(E)$) $$\varepsilon:=\inf_{x\in\overline B_r(0)}|f(x)|>0\tag3.$$ Now, since $f$ is uniformly norm-continuous, there is a $\delta>0$ with $$|f(x)-f(y)|<\frac\varepsilon2\;\;\;\text{for all }x,y\in E\text{ with }\left\|x-y\right\|_E<\delta\tag4.$$ Let $k\in\mathbb N$ and $0=t_0<\cdots<t_k=1$ with $$\max_{1\le i\le k}|t_{i-1}-t_i|<\frac\delta r\tag5.$$ Then $$|f(t_{i-1}x)-f(t_ix)|<\frac\varepsilon2\;\;\;\text{for all }1\le i\le k\text{ and }x\in\overline B_r(0)\tag6.$$ Since $0\not\in f(E)$, this yields $$\left|1-\frac{f(t_ix)}{f(t_{i-1}x)}\right|<\frac\varepsilon{2|f(t_{i-1}x)|}\le\frac12\tag7$$ for all $1\le i\le k$ and $x\in\overline B_r(0)$. Let $\ln$ denote the principal branch of the complex algorithm and $$g(x):=\sum_{i=1}^k\ln\frac{f(t_ix)}{f(t_{i-1}x)}\;\;\;\text{or }x\in\overline B_r(0).$$ By $(7)$, $$\frac{f(t_ix)}{f(t_{i-1}x)}\in B_{\frac12}(1)\subseteq\mathbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in\overline B_r(0)\tag8$$ and hence (since $\ln$ is continuous on $\mathbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]$) we conclude that $g$ is norm-continuous. Moreover, $g(0)=0$ and $$e^{g(x)}=f(x)\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in\overline B_r(0).\tag9$$ By

By Lemma 1, $g$ is unique. Now let's denote this $g$ by $g_r$. Then, by uniqueness, $$g_{r_1}=\left.g_{r_2}\right|_{\overline B_{r_1}(0)}\;\;\;\text{for all }0<r_1\le r_2\tag{10}$$ and hence $$g(x):=g_r(x)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\overline B_r(0)\text{ and }r>0\tag{11}$$ is a well-defined function on $E$ satisfying the desired properties.

Comment: As far as I understand, you're generalizing (Ap.2.6) - now $E$ is not a euclidean ball, but some linear space. Yes, this is true, but it doesn't answer your question. For example, the same statement doesn't hold for all $E$ being a circle.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz Thank you for your comment. I actually only need the result for $E$ being a normed vector space (not a general metric space). But if I got you right, you agree to my answer and that the result holds in that situation, right?

Comment: Yes, it holds in this particular case.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz From the definition of $g_r$, we easily see that $g_r$ is continuous with respect to both $\tau$ and $\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_E$ (i.e. the corresponding subspace topologies on $\overline B_r(0)$). Am I missing something or aren't we able to immediately conclude that the function $g$ defined by $(11)$ is $\tau$-continuous? I'm asking cause I found a reference where it is explicitly remarked that it follows from the representation of $g_r$ that the restriction of $g$ to $\overline B_r(0)$ is $\tau$-continuous; but this would be obvious if even $g$ itself is $\tau$-continous.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz I'd still be interested in what you think about the question in my last comment.

Comment: Indeed, the formula for $g_r \colon \overline{B}_r(0) \to \mathbb{C}$ implies directly that it's $\tau$-continuous. As you suggested, this in turn implies that $g \colon E \to \mathbb{C}$ is $\tau$-continuous when restricted to any ball.

Comment: (11) itself doesn't guarantee that the resulting $g$ is $\tau$-continuous. What you have in mind is probably an argument based on the silent assumption that balls $B_r(0)$ are $\tau$-open (which doesn't have to be true).

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz Thank you for your comment. Assume for the moment that in the statement of Theorem 2 $\tau$ is the topology generated by the norm on $E$ and that we explicitly assume that $(3)$ holds for all $r>0$. Given that, I wonder whether it is really necessary to assume that $f$ is uniformly norm-continuous. I think it is sufficient to assume that $f$ is an arbitrary function $E\to\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ such that the restriction of $f$ to $\overline B_r(0)$ is uniformly norm-continuous and satisfies $(3)$ for all $r>0$.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz The proof holds then line by line (if I'm missing something, please correct me). The crucial question is: Are we then still be able that $g$ as constructed is uniformly norm-continuous (on the whole set $E$)? But maybe that's a silly consideration, since the assumption that the restriction of any function $E\to\mathbb C$ to every closed ball to be uniformly norm-continuous is equivalent to the function being norm-continuous on the whole space. Is that the case?

Comment: There's a lot of questions here (to many to address one by one), and they're getting further and further away from the original topic, so I suggest opening a new question.

Comment: For one thing of what I'm after, I've asked a separate question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4122549/47771. Would be great if you could take a look.